# Get Facebook Feed Posts from a specific date range

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Ok here is the deal

I am trying to pull posts from a group based on a date range so I am using this

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<groupID>/feed/?since=1398902400&until=1398988800&access_token=<accesstoken>

since= 2014-05-01 and until= 2014-05-02
```

I am using unix time and it looks like it works but when you start paginating

I can see posts from 2014-04-30 which is out of the requested date range.

Can somebody help me figure out why is this happening?

Comment: Hi, is the above quoted the only code you applied / tried?

Comment: yes is the only. I tried looking trying to figure out if it was possible via FQL query but the created_time is not index-able

Comment: From what I can tell, you should be able to use since and until parameters. And you did do that. Have you tried playing around with the parameters? Maybe it's a format issue?

Comment: @andrejohannsen217 never helped me he just wanted to see if I was willing to pay $20 for the answer. If somebody got the answer for this it will be awesome.

Comment: Do you happen to have a sample of this that we can take a look at?

Answer (score 0):

From what you just provided us. It's correct that you use the unix code.  However, the code you provided has one tiny issue that may/may not be the cause for the error.

You provided us with:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<groupID>/feed/?since=1398902400&until=1398988800&access_token=<accesstoken>
```

You may just need to change it to the following:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<groupID>/feed?since=1398902400&until=1398988800&access_token=<accesstoken>
```

The small issue is just syntax. Instead of a / you just need to remove it and go straight to `feed?since=`...

Aside from that, that's all I can see is wrong with it.

Comment: Thanks for the help but the issue persist. As I paginate thru the data it shows posts from "created_time": "2014-04-30T23:17:45+0000" which is outside of the specified date range

Comment: Check with this group ID 1400366526844437 and you will see what I am talking about. The first page shows fine and even the second but once you reach the 3rd page instead of seeing posts from 2014-05-02 you see posts from 2014-04-30

Comment: @Manny i am also facing the same issue did you find any solution for this then kindly please let me know.